# Need a .NET Framework solution for IEEE-754 float/double parse and ToString

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, ieee-754

**.NET framework** does not give me expected results for float/double parsing and ToString. It is fixed in .NET 6 (even in .NET Core 3.0). However, I cannot migrate my whole project from .NET framework 4.X to 6.

Here an example. **0x5a0e1bca** is **10000000272564224** in **float** representation. I executed following code using both .NET Framework 4.7.2 and .NET 6.

```
var fl = BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] { 0xCA, 0x1B, 0x0E, 0x5A }, 0);
Console.WriteLine(fl.ToString("g20"));
```

.NET Framework 4.7.2 output:

```
10000000300000000
```

.NET 6 output:

```
10000000272564224
```

10000000300000000 is not even represented in float.

Does anybody know why this happens and how I can overcome it?

Comment: Hi @Murat: I altered your question a bit to prevent closure due to "looking for tools". Feel free to change it back if I misunderstood.

Comment: I suspect value is rounded to 9 significant places and zeros appended.  If the value was the max `float`, would you expect a 39 digit exact result or be satisfied with a result that is correct to 9 significant digits?  Even IEEE754 does not require 39 in that case.  IIRC it only requires 9+3.